# Weird integral (Pareto distribution)

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove that a function $\mathcal{f}$ is a Pareto distribution, but i'm stuck here:
$$\int_1^{+\infty} x^{-1}(x^{-2})^{n+2-i}(1-x^{-2})^{i-2}\:dx$$

I would like to solve this integral without using any numerical methods, can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: i and n are real numbers.

Comment: [Back up a little](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What $f$ were you trying to prove took what form? Why did that problem reduce to computing this integral? Why are you stuck on it? Likely, what you really want to focus on is something different. That said, try $x=\sec t$. I think it gives you $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+3-2i}t\sin^{2i-3}tdt=\operatorname{B}(i-1,\,n+2-i)$, but you'll want to double-check that.

Comment: @J.G. thanks for your answer. i will try that. This integral appears from the marginal function of a previous function.

Comment: J.G.'s result is also $\frac{\Gamma (i-1) \Gamma (-i+n+2)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$